# WP Admin Bar transparent on some pages (.screen-reader-shortcut)

Tags: css, admin-bar

I have an issue where the WP Admin Bar is transparent on some pages on the site. It's there and all the links are clickable, however, it is not viable.

I am using a child version of the Divi Theme but the issue is still there when I make the switch back to the standard theme.

When I inspect the page I notice that the following CSS is active.

```
#wpadminbar .screen-reader-shortcut {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000em;
}
```

If I remove the 'top: -1000em;' then the bar appears. I am not sure why style is active and it is being taken from the 'admin-bar.min.css' which I have not overwritten or made any changes to.

My question is has anyone else come across this issue and do you have a recommendations to fix it without just overwriting the style?

Comment: Check to see where that property is set.  You're using the Inspector to find the property - you need to also use it to identify the specific stylesheet the property comes from.  That way you can determine if it is coming from a plugin or your theme, and if so, which one.

Comment: I have already inspected the style and it is coming from the 'admin-bar.min.css' file which is a WP file. It only creates this issue on some pages and I am not sure why that is.